# Angular http call does not convert nested array

Tags: angular, typescript

My application has Angular 12 client and Java Spring REST API.
For one of the API that returns array, the http call converts the instances to associated instances in TypeScript correctly. This is as follows:

```
this.http.post<UserSearchResult[]>(serverURL, userSearchCriteria, httpOptions )
              .subscribe(
              (response) => {
               console.table(response);
               regComp.processSearchCallBack(response);
              );
```

The associated API signature is as follows:

```
public UserSearchResult[] searchUser(@RequestBody UserSearchCriteria userContactInfoRemote)
```

But when I nest the array in another wrapper class called UserSearchCriteria like this:

Server side VO:

```
public class UserSearchCriteria {

  String scFirstName;
  String scLastName;
  
  UserSearchResult[] usr;
}
```

Server side API signature :

```
public UserSearchCriteria searchUser(@RequestBody UserSearchCriteria userContactInfoRemote)
```

Client side TypeSript :

```
export class UserSearchCriteria{
  
  scFirstName : string = "";
  scLastName : string = "";
  usr : UserSearchResult[] = [];
}
```

and http call as :

```
this.http.post<UserSearchCriteria>(serverURL, userSearchCriteria, httpOptions )
              .subscribe(
              (response) => {
                console.log('callForUserSearch : response');
                console.table(response);
               
                regComp.processSearchCallBack(response);
              
              });
```

I end up with usr as undefined error.
I tried casting it using as and <> operator with first casting to unknown. I also tried casting to Object[] and any[] but usr stays as undefined.

So I have two questions :

What changes are necessary in http call to directly get the array of UserSearchResult in the UserSearchCriteria wrapper.

Secondly,
How to cast a reference (which is pointing to an array of Object) into array of UserSearchCriteria.

Thanks,

Nealesh

Here is sample output of API that return UserSearchCriteria:

[image]

Comment: Did you check the http response body? Is it a correct array? There is no example output of the API.

Comment: Hi CSchulz, I added sample output please.

Comment: 1.-Add a type to the httpClient.post **not** do anything. Only help typescript to show errors if not match the type we use with the type we use in response. 2.-In your response, usrArray is an Object, not an array. 3.- remember that your services return Observables, you subscribe in components.4.- you can use pipe map to return only a property or severals in your service, e.g.:`this.http.post<UserSearchCriteria>(..).pipe(map((x:any)=>x.usrArray)`